# Sphere texture does not cover the whole sphere

Tags: javascript, three.js

When the texture is applied on the sphere, ugly folds appear at poles and part of the texture is missing.

[image: Weird mapping at poles]

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
var load = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("e.jpg");
load.anisotropy = 8;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: load,
    overdraw: true
});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a sphere with twice the number of [circles of latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_latitude).
Try this :

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI);
var load = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("e.jpg");
load.anisotropy = 8;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: load,
    overdraw: true
});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);
```

By the way, you can leave extra parameters to default by not passing those to the constructor :

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try to first load required image and on load use following code.

```
var earthTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("e.jpg");
var earthGeometery = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 50, 50);
var earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: earthTexture,
        transparent: false
    });
```

> imgObj : is image object

Comment: Better to use `THREE.TextureLoader()`